# Insert RTF string into Ms Word using Open XML

Tags: wpf, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

I have a table in SQL Server that contains RTF code like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Lintel Inspection
\par }
```

I then have a template word document that I need to insert this into and just wondering how to do that using OpenXML SDK?

I know a bit like "altChunks" is used but not sure how.

Any coding reference also works. I had searched around but with no luck.

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever figure out how to do this or if it was possible?

Comment: @bporter, I didnt found any solutions to that.